# How do I get intellisense to know the structure of a JSON parameter (visual studio 2012)

Tags: javascript, json, visual-studio-2012

This is concerning Visual Studio Version 2012.  Please keep this in mind as you answer...

I would like to know how to get intellisense to recognize what the structure of a JSON object that a constructor function is accepting as an parameter.

Say you have something like this:

```
somethingObject = function(blueprint) {
   this.target = blueprint.target;
   this.propertyFromBlueprintNested = blueprint.nestedSomething.thePropertyIwant;
}
```

When instantiating a new somethingObject in Visual Studio is there way for intellisense to be recognize that the JSON structure is while you are writing it.  Consider this:

```
var s = new somethingObject({
     //<<  Visual studio would suggest target, or nestedSomething here
}
```

I am open to consdering another IDE that does this sort of thing with JavaScript properly.  I am currently evaluating JetBrains WebStorm

TO THE PERSON WHO SUGGEST RESHAPER:

Here is what I get:

(I would put an image here I need more reputation though :-(

Bottom line is, the property just doesn't show like yours do.

I think I may need to give it up.

Comment: So you want Visual Studio to scan the code so it knows that `target` and `nestedSomething.thePropertyIwant` are used? Perhaps you could give TypeScript a go.

Answer (score 1):

[Jetbrains Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) supports this: [version 8 EAP](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+8+EAP) (soon to be released)

[image]

Comment: Is there something you have to set in Resharper to do this cause i don't see that behavior.  I tried Resharper in the past and it was disappointing.  It shows A LOT of stuff but never the stuff I am looking for.

Comment: I should note I have typescript installed too.

Comment: @NickBirke I do apologise I was using Resharper 8 EAP on the computer I tested from. Have updated answer. It does work tho that is a screenshot from VS! You just press Ctrl-Space and thats what you should see. Resharper bumped up support for javascript significantly starting for R#6